# Cannot use any terminal based MP3 player

Tags: debian, mp3

Currently I am using a Debian 11 system. Something seems to be completely off with music players. I first tried `cmus` to no avail (cmus would give errors on startup and not show any mp3 files) I then tried `mocp`. Using `mocp` I can see the files but upon trying to play said files it will say "playing" for a fraction of a second and stop with no errors. I can play said files with `ffplay` just fine, but the original goal was to have a decent looking terminal-based mp3 player to play my songs.

I have tried using `mocp -D` and I will give the logs that stand out here:

```
Nov 24 23:47:18.447269: interface.c:674 ev_file_tags(): Received tags for /home/me/music/song.mp3
Nov 24 23:47:18.447918: interface.c:692 ev_file_tags(): Tags apply to the currently played file.
Nov 24 23:47:18.448008: interface.c:3482 dequeue_events(): done
Nov 24 23:47:18.460880: interface.c:1115 server_event(): EVENT: 0x0f
```

but this doesn't really tell me anything. If it's of use, I have installed `cmus` both via building from github and from the Debian repository and `mocp` from the Debian repository.

Comment: I use [mpg123](https://mpg123.org/index.shtml), it works great.

Comment: What were the errors that `cmus` gave? Where they related to the `mocp` errors? Please [edit] and update your question with the errors - they may be of use.

Answer (score 0):

A very, very, very long time ago (Debian 5 IIRC), I used [mp3blaster](http://mp3blaster.sf.net) and I was very happy with it.

It seems it is still [available at Debian 11](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mp3blaster), so give it a try (I am not sure if it will work with pulseaudio if you use it)